# ViewScoped no funciona

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee

Tengo un Bean que tiene @SessionScoped y funciona perfectamente, sin embargo quiero usar @ViewScoped, pero al cambiarle  la anotación deja de funcionar y siempre me marca el error Target Unreachable

@ViewScoped lo estoy importando con:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
```

No estoy seguro de que es lo que está mal.

Lo que quiero es que las variables que uso dentro de ese Bean mueran al cambiar de vista.

Esté es el código de mi Bean:

```
package mx.materiam.backend.controllers;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import mx.materiam.entities.OrdenProduccion;


@Named(value = "ordenProduccionController")
@ViewScoped
public class ordenProduccionController implements Serializable{

private OrdenProduccion ordenProduccion;


public ordenProduccionController() {
    ordenProduccion = new OrdenProduccion();
}



public void foo(){
    System.out.println("hola");
}

public OrdenProduccion getOrdenProduccion() {
    return ordenProduccion;
}

public void setOrdenProduccion(OrdenProduccion ordenProduccion) {
    this.ordenProduccion = ordenProduccion;
}

}
```

Comment: Agrega la anotación @ManagedBean y se soluciona!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando JSF y CDI, denotado por el uso de `@Named` (CDI). Con JSF 2.0 y 2.1, no se podía tener un managed bean manejado por CDI que sea `@ViewScoped` puesto que no lo soportaba. Desde JSF 2.2 en adelante, existe una anotación nueva de `@ViewScoped` dentro del paquete `javax.faces.view`. Tu código debería lucir así:

```
package mx.materiam.backend.controllers;
import java.io.Serializable;

//Aquí cambias el nombre del paquete
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import mx.materiam.entities.OrdenProduccion;

@Named(value = "ordenProduccionController")
@ViewScoped
public class OrdenProduccionController implements Serializable {
    /* resto de tu código */
}
```

Si usas JSF 2.0 o 2.1, simplemente **no puedes hacerlo**.

Answer (score 1):

Un truco para que funcione @ViewScoped con CDI en JSF 2.0 y 2.1, y Java EE 6 es usar Apache Deltaspike.  http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/jsf.html

Deltaspike automáticamente reconoce los ViewScoped y otros scopes de los packages javax.faces.bean... dándole su respectivo scope en CDI.

Para que tu @ViewScoped funcione, basta con añadir las librerias core y jsf de DeltaSpike a tu War (sea con ant, maven, gradle, etc...), y listo.

Verás que se añade una variale dswid en las URL pero es normal.

Comment: Tu respuesta seria mejor valorada si agregas un pequeño ejemplo

Comment: Tal como dice mi respuesta, es automático, en la misma manera que tiene el consultante su código funciona, tan solo añadiendo las dependencias de Deltaspike a sus librerias y eso depende de si usa ant, maven, gradle, etc.

Comment: El problema es justo ese parámetro adicional en el query string. Esto es similar a `@ConversationScoped` que termina siendo más un problema que un beneficio.

Comment: Hemos integrado Apache Deltaspike en produccion ya dos años en varios proyectos Java EE 6, desde su version 0.5 y jamás ha sido un problema la variable de URL dswid, los ViewScoped funcionan de maravilla y tal como se espera.